# how to use matplotlib to plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am confused with using matplotlib.pyplot in python to plot the values that I generated from a for loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
c = (np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), np.random.rand())

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

x = list(range(10, 101, 10))
y = list(range(20, 150, 13))
```

This is a part of my code:

```
for i in range(0,10):
   for j in range(0,10):
       z = x[i] + y[j] 
       plt.plot(x[i],z, color = c)
```

I am trying to plot the z that I generated from loops. i would like to use the values of `y` as the x-axis and generate a new series (line) for each of `x`. 
That is saying plot the z values in lines, for each line the z value has the same x value.
From my code, it shows a blank plot

Comment: How are we supposed to help here? See [mcve]. Your code is not runnable at all, hence nobody can know what the problem might be.

Comment: I would like to plot the z values in lines, for each line the z value has the same x value.

Comment: Can you show what your plot _should_ look like?

Comment: I posted a plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the x and y values for the entire line when you call `plt.plot()`. Therefore, one possible (though quite messy) way of doing it is to append the values to a list, plot the line, then clear the list.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

x = list(range(10, 101, 10))
y = list(range(20, 150, 13))

for i in range(0,10):
    if i != 0:
        ax.plot(x_list, z_list)

    z_list = []
    x_list = []

    for j in range(0,10):
        z = x[i] + y[j] 
        z_list.append(z)
        x_list.append(y[j])

plt.show()
```

Which produces the following figure:

[image]